# TinyMce add multi elements to activeEditor.dom

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4, tinymce-plugins

I am using TinyMce4 i have pluging that add div to my editor

My code:

```
tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.AddContent', {

    init: function (ed, url) {
     ed.addCommand('mceAddContent', function () {
     var editor = tinymce.activeEditor;
     var ed_body = $(editor.getBody());
     tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.add(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getBody(), 'div', { 'class': 'draggableTemplate' }, 'Add you element here...');

        }),

        // Register example button
        ed.addButton('addcontent', {
            title: 'Add content at the end',
            cmd: 'mceAddContent',
            image: url + '/img/addcontent.png',
            onclick: function () {

            }

        });

    }

});


tinymce.PluginManager.add('addcontent', tinymce.plugins.AddContent);
```

Now what i need is to add not only div

i need element Link(a) inside of this div with href and class

Example:

```
<div class='draggableTemplate'> 
<a href="#scroll1" class="scrollto">Link to element</a>
</div>
```

How can i use  tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.add or some think else to add div with link(a) like you see it in example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution it is very simple:

you just need to change

> tinyMCE.activeEditor.getBody()

in

> tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.add(...)

to your element that you need,and this will insert Link(a) to your element

```
var yourElement= tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.add(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getBody(), 'div', { 'class': 'draggableTemplate' }, ' ');

tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.add(yourElement, 'a', { 'href': '#scroll1'), 'class': ' scrollto ' }, 'Insert your anchor image or text first before you remove this...');
```

Full code:

```
tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.AddContent', {

    init: function (ed, url) {
     ed.addCommand('mceAddContent', function () {
     var editor = tinymce.activeEditor;
     var ed_body = $(editor.getBody());

    var yourElement= tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.add(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getBody(), 'div', { 'class': 'draggableTemplate' }, ' ');

    tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.add(yourElement, 'a', { 'href': '#scroll1'), 'class': ' scrollto ' }, 'Link to element');



        }),

        // Register example button
        ed.addButton('addcontent', {
            title: 'Add content at the end',
            cmd: 'mceAddContent',
            image: url + '/img/addcontent.png',
            onclick: function () {

            }

        });

    }

});


tinymce.PluginManager.add('addcontent', tinymce.plugins.AddContent);
```

Result:

```
<div class='draggableTemplate'> 
<a href="#scroll1" class="scrollto">Link to element</a>
</div>
```